# How to get real data types and allowed values of fields for a defect

Tags: rally

On using the typedef() method from pyral(version - 1.4.2) library, I am able to get the fields for the respective artifacts types(eg. defect),
but in the response -> the data type (attribute type) for the fields differs from the one seen on the UI. eg. for drop-down field I'm getting 'Rating/String' as AttributeType instead of 'DROP_DOWN'.
how could I get the real data type as the one seen on UI through the response?
Is there any other api that I can use to get all the fields and there datatype, allowed values attributes for a defect?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [WSAPI docs](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/), you'll find that the `AttributeDefinition` object has many different elements. The `AttributeType` is the one you're accessing which can be one of the following values:

"BINARY_DATA", "BOOLEAN", "COLLECTION", "DATE", "DECIMAL", "INTEGER", "OBJECT", "QUANTITY", "RATING", "RAW", "STATE", "STRING", "TEXT", "MAP", "WEB_LINK"

But it also has an element called `RealAttributeType` which can be one of the following values:

"BINARY_DATA", "OBJECT", "QUANTITY", "RATING", "STATE", "RAW", "COLLECTION", "TEXT", "BOOLEAN", "INTEGER", "DECIMAL", "WEB_LINK", "DATE", "STRING", "DROP_DOWN", "MULTI_VALUE", "USER"

Have you tried accessing the `RealAttributeType` to see its value?

Comment: I'm not getting 'RealAttributeType' element in response of typedef().

Comment: Are you specifying what fields to fetch? Did you try either including RealAttributeType in the fetch object or setting fetch to true? I can see the RealAttributeType when targeting the Attributes endpoint directly (after specifying fetch), but maybe there is a limitation in Pyral that I'm not aware of.